# Контроль над или за

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно пишется: "контроль над работой сотрудников" или "за работой"? Просьба объяснить, каким правилом это регулируется.

Answer (score 1):

И еще есть вариант "контроль работы".

А вот правило - только одно. Вкус автора. Т.е. какие-то правила можно найти, такие например:

*Слово КОНТРОЛЬ употребляется со следующими предлогами:
1) за чем и над чем - при отглагольных существительных: контроль за / над расходованием средств;
2) за чем - при существительных, обозначающих действие или признак: контроль за работой станка; контроль за качеством работы;
3) над кем-чем - при существительных отвлеченных и при одушевленных существительных: контроль над производством; контроль над молодыми специалистами;
4) чего - в официальной и профессионально-технической речи: контроль деятельности выборных органов; контроль готовой продукции.*
©gramota.ru

Но они носят максимум рекомендательный характер. 
В данном контексте мне больше нравится именно "контроль работы".