# Как правильно согласовывать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, существительные

Здравствуйте. Как правильно согласовывать слово "контроль" с другими, например: закреплены функции контроля ***по*** выполнению учебного плана, закреплены функции контроля ***за*** выполнением учебного плана или закреплены функции ***контроля выполнения*** учебного плана?
Запуталась. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как пишет Грамота.ру, возможны 2 варианта: "контроль за выполнением учебного плана" и "контроль выполнения учебного плана", но более употребительный первый вариант. http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EA%EE%ED%F2%F0%EE%EB%FC+%E2%FB%EF%EE%EB%ED%E5%ED%E8%FF

А вот "контроль выполнения плана" уже спорный случай. Здесь нанизываются слова в одном падеже, что считается стилистической ошибкой. Правильнее "контроль за выполнением плана".

Answer (score 0):

Это вопрос уже обсуждался здесь: [Контроль над или за](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0)
На мой взгляд правильнее сказать "контроль чего-то".